# WP: Can I use Template Hierarchy page and templates together or am I talking about same thing?

Tags: wordpress, templates, hierarchy

I'm trying to create WP site with different templates with different functionality but in same web page with same header and footer.

So my question is, Is Page Hierarchy (page-about.php) different than Template Hierarchy?
If its different thing, can i use both of them in same page?

Ex: templates/about.php + pages/about.php = about page with about template etc...

Answer (score 0):

The template hierarchy boils down to how WordPress decides which template to load when a URL is requested (when you type a URL in your browser address bar). In your question above, you mention `page-about.php` - this is one of the many templates you might have in your theme folder. When someone requests the page `example.com/about` on your website, WordPress will load the `page-about.php` template because it is the best match according to the rules in template hierarchy.

For info on exactly how the template hierarchy 'matches' URLs to templates, see:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy